# How to read a Multipart file as a string in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data

I want to post a text file from my desktop using Advanced Rest Client.
This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vsp/debug/compareConfig/{deviceIp:.*}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }, produces = { "application/json" })

public ResponseEntity<SuccessResult> compareCLIs(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable("deviceIp") String device) 
{
log.info(file.getOriginalFilename());
byte[] bytearr = file.getBytes();
log.info("byte length: ", bytearr.length);
log.info("Size : ", file.getSize());

}
```

This does not return any value for byte length or file size. I want to read the file values to a StringBuffer. Can someone provide pointers regarding this? I am not sure if I need to save this file before parsing it to a string. If so how do I save the file in the workspace?

Comment: You should avoid retrieving all the bytes at once. Instead, use `MultiPartFile#getInputStream` and use that stream to fill your `StringBuilder` (you don't need to use `StringBuffer`) or any other way to consume the data.

Comment: hi..did you get the solution. please add the solution.

Answer (score 50):

If you want to load the content of a Multipart file into a String, the easiest solution is:

```
String content = new String(file.getBytes());
```

Or, if you want to specify the charset:

```
String content = new String(file.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

However, if your file is huge, this solution is maybe not the best.

Comment: This is not working for me, doesn't return UTF characters.

Comment: Once the data is sent from the client, to my controller method. Is the entire file not loaded in memory at this point? Would reading the file at once cause problem then? @OlivierTerrien

Answer (score 13):

First, this is not related to Spring, and, second, you don't need to save the file to parse it.

To read the content of a Multipart file into a String you can use [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/) IOUtils class like this

```
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new   ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
String myString = IOUtils.toString(stream, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: `MultipartFile` is a Spring type -- so the question is related to Spring.  But once you call `getBytes()` you've entered the domain of generic Java.

Answer (score 3):

The given answers are correct but the top answer said it's not **efficient for large files** and the reason is that it keeps the whole file in memory which means if you are uploading a 2gb file it will consume that much of memory. Instead of doing that we can read the file **line by line** and Apache Commons IO provides a nice API for it.

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(theFile, "UTF-8");
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String line = it.nextLine();
        // do something with line
    }
} finally {
    LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
}
```

[source](https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file)